# The Screen Manager is not returning Desired Output in Kivy Python

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy, scrollview

There is no such error shown in the Python output shell.

What I want is that , the first page should be the Login page or as here, the "ConnectingPage" then Welcome Should Be shown, and then at last a Set of buttons named from 0 to 99 be shown.

Here is the code :

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, FallOutTransition
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.base import runTouchApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window


class ConnectingPage(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        self.cols = 2

        self.add_widget(Label(text = "Usename:"))
        self.username = TextInput(multiline=False)
        self.add_widget(self.username)

        self.add_widget(Label(text = "Password:"))
        self.password = TextInput(multiline=False,password = True)
        self.add_widget(self.password)

        self.joinbutton = Button(text="Join")
        self.joinbutton.bind(on_release = self.click_join_button)
        self.add_widget(Label())  
        self.add_widget(self.joinbutton)
        
    def click_join_button(self, instance):
        username = self.username.text
        password = self.password.text
    #if username == "venu gopal" and password == "venjar":

        MyApp.screen_manager.current = "Info"
        MyApp.screen_manager.current = "Chat"
        
class InfoPage(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 1
        self.message = Label(text = "welcome",halign="center", valign="middle", font_size=30)
        self.add_widget(self.message)

class SomeApp(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        layout = GridLayout(cols=1, spacing=10, size_hint_y=None)
        # Make sure the height is such that there is something to scroll.
        layout.bind(minimum_height=layout.setter('height'))
        for i in range(100):
            btn = Button(text=str(i), size_hint_y=None, height=40)
            layout.add_widget(btn)
        root = ScrollView(size_hint=(1, None), size=(Window.width, Window.height))
        root.add_widget(layout)
        if __name__ == "__main__":
            runTouchApp(root)

class MyApp(App):
    screen_manager = ScreenManager(transition=FallOutTransition(duration=2))  # this make screen_manager a class vaiable

    def build(self):
        # self.screen_manager = ScreenManager()
        self.connecting_page = ConnectingPage()
        screen = Screen(name='Connect')
        screen.add_widget(self.connecting_page)
        self.screen_manager.add_widget(screen)  # add screen to ScreenManager

        # Info page
        self.info_page = InfoPage()
        screen = Screen(name='Info')
        screen.add_widget(self.info_page)
        self.screen_manager.add_widget(screen)  # add screen to ScreenManager

        # Chat App
        self.chat_app = SomeApp()
        screen = Screen(name='Chat')
        screen.add_widget(self.chat_app)
        self.screen_manager.add_widget(screen)  # add screen to ScreenManager 

        # return ConnectingPage()
        return self.screen_manager


if __name__ == "__main__": 
    MyApp().run()
```

The Problem is that: the set of Buttons are getting shown in the start. When the Cross is pressed to close the kivy window, then the Login page is shown and then "welcome" and then the buttons again.
I want It to show from the second Step.

What I believe is that the "line 61" in the code is making a problem. When the code is run it first shows the buttons and so on.

Please Help me find the solution for the above Problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `__init__()` method of the `SomeApp` class starts an `App` running with the lines:

```
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        runTouchApp(root)
```

and that `runTouchApp()` does not return until that `App` completes. So when you run your code, it stops a the line:

```
self.chat_app = SomeApp()
```

To fix that, just replace:

```
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        runTouchApp(root)
```

with:

```
    self.add_widget(root)
```